# Latin Squares Problem - Statistics

Tags: statistics

I am a little confused about this problem I found in my book:

Their design used four subjects as blocks and assigned three treatments to each subject in a random order, one drug on each of three different days.

I'm supposed to come up with a design based on Latin squares. The context of the problem does not really make sense to me. I know that one of the nuisance factors, subjects, has four levels, while the other nuisance factor, days, has three. For a Latin squares design, shouldn't the levels be the same? I would only see how a Latin squares design would work if there were three, not four, subjects. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment, but I can't comment yet. Perhaps the missing treatment is the control? If it is, then you would have four subjects and four treatments, which can suitably be placed in a $4\times 4$ latin square.